# Triggering WebJob Method Based on Message Property

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have an Azure WebJobs project which handles a number of time-consuming tasks triggered by website actions. It works fine.

But the mapping from message to method call uses magic strings:

```
public class SomeClass
{        
    public async Task ProcessMessage(
        [ QueueTrigger( "%" + nameof( ContainerQueueConstants.FilteredVoterFiles ) + "%" ) ] AgencyOutreachMessage
            msg,
        TextWriter azureLogWriter
    )
    {
        PhaseNames.SetNames( "Exporting Data", "Job Completed" );

        await ExecuteFromMessage( msg, azureLogWriter, Launch );
    }
}

public class ContainerQueueConstants
{
    public const string ImportFile = "import-file";
    public const string VoterTraits = "voter-traits";
    public const string Voter = "voter";
    public const string FilteredVoterFiles = "filtered-voter-files";
}
```

I'd like to get away from using hard-coded strings for queue names. Ideally, I'd like to be able to route a message to a particular method based on the value of a property contained in the message.

But I'm not sure if that's even possible, at least in the 1.1.x version of the WebJobs SDK.

Suggestions or advice appreciated.

Comment: If you want to call a method based on a property within a message, why not just deserialize the message, check the property value, and call the desired method based on the property value? Or am I misunderstanding and you'd like to monitor multiple queues, each with a different queue name that you do not want to hard code?

Comment: I'd like to do the latter, Rob: monitor multiple queues which don't have hard-coded names.

Your idea would work fine except that, for other reasons, I operate each of the current queues as Singletons, and if I push all the messages through a single Singleton queue they'll get needlessly deferred. Although that may be the best available alternative, all things considered.

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to use the QueueTriggerAttribute and not just create N CloudQueue instances to monitor N different storage queues? Or would using N different CloudQueue instances work?
I suppose I should also ask if the receiving application is going to be a WebJob.

Comment: Umm, maybe because I wasn't aware of the CloudQueue approach :)? Good suggestion, for which thanx. If the current approach I'm taking to de-convolving the webjob library I wrote doesn't work I'll definitely give that a go. I presume going the CloudQueue route means I have to take over responsibility for polling for messages, deleting them when processed, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using N CloudQueue instances to monitor N different Storage Queues. Since you're doing this in a WebJob, you will probably do this as a continuous webjob and have to perform the polling for each queue yourself. You will also have to take responsibility for removing successfully processed messages.

The QueueTriggerAttribute has built-in support for deadlettering. I do not believe that there is automatic deadlettering support if you do not use the QueueTriggerAttribute.

Comment: What's deadlettering support?

Comment: Dead lettering is a queue concept for handling poison messages. A poison message is a message that has been dequeued and unsuccessfully processed a set number of times. It's a great feature that keeps messages that can't be processed from living in an eternal read/fail/lease expire/read/fail/lease expire... loop. When you're using the QueueTriggerAttribute with triggered WebJobs, messages that have been delivered X times unsuccessfully will be put into a separate queue called [queue name]-poison. You can look at and deal with these messages later.

Comment: You can read about poison messages and automatic deadlettering with the QueueTriggerAttribute here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to#poison

Comment: Got it. Thought that was what you meant, but hadn't seen it called dead lettering before. Thanx!